# submitHandler Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Estoy modificando mi ajax para usar las validaciones de Jquery Validate, estoy usando esta estructura y me encuentro con un error de sintaxis que no puedo encontrar.

```
function AgregarCliente(){

    // validate and process form here  
    $('#form_cliente').validate({
        rules: {
            // Set rules for special fields (email/phone?)
        },

        // JQuery's awesome submit handler.
        submitHandler(function(form) {

            // Create variables from the form
            var to = $('input#to').val();
            var fullname = $('input#fullname').val(); 
            var emailaddress = $('input#emailaddress').val();  
            var message = $('textarea#message').val();

            // Create variables that will be sent in a URL string to mail.php
            var dataString = 'to=' + to + '&fullname='+ fullname + '&emailaddress=' + emailaddress + '&message=' + message;

            // The AJAX
            $.ajax({  
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/path/to/mail.php',
              data: dataString,
              success(function(data) {

              }),
                error(function(){
                    alert('Whoops! This didn\'t work. Please contact us.')
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

}

La consola me marca el error en la linea "submitHandler(function(form)" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

saludos gracias !

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a la [documentación de validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) es de la siguiente forma:

```
submitHandler = function(form) {
// Tú código de acciones a realizar
}
```

sin embargo tienes:

```
submitHandler(function(form)
```

para evitar estos detalles te sugiero armes (digamos) el esqueleto completo y luego rellenes, es decir algo como:

```
$("#form_cliente").validate({
  rules : {
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // Todo lo que va
    $.ajax({  
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/path/to/mail.php',
       data: dataString,
       success:function(data) {

       },
       error : function(){
            // Te sugiero ver la documentación y agregar los demas parámetros que recibe en caso de error
            // lo anterior te permitirá saber más "preciso" que error se reportar y por consiguiente podrás depurar y corregir.
            alert('Whoops! This didn\'t work. Please contact us.');
       }
     });
  }
});
```

así por el estilo y con ello listo empieces a llenar con la funcionalidad deseada.

Por cierto en tu código veo un `return false` ¿siempre retornara false? claro puede lo estes usando asi por el detalle que tienes. Éxitos.

**Importate** En la declaración de `error` y `success` en el ajax tienes el mismo error de sintáxis.
Recuerda cada instrucción terminarla en ";" no omitas indicar de forma explícita cada fin de instrucción.